# How to set state of UIButton in function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a for loop that loops through an array of object type Note that has the property fingering which is set to a button.

The for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [Bb_major.scaleNotes count]; i++) {
        valve1.highlighted = NO;
        valve2.highlighted = NO;
        valve3.highlighted = NO;
        valve4.highlighted = NO;

        [Scale tutorial:valve1 :valve2 :valve3 :valve4 :Bb_major.scaleNotes[i]]; 
}
```

The tutorial method:

```
+(void)tutorial:(UIButton *)button1 :(UIButton *)button2 :(UIButton *)button3 :(UIButton *)button4 :(Note *)Note {

switch ([Note.fingering count]) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        button1 = Note.fingering[0];

        button1.highlighted = YES;

        sleep(1.0);

        break;
    case 2:

        button1 = Note.fingering[0];
        button2 = Note.fingering[1];

        button1.highlighted = YES;
        button2.highlighted = YES;

        sleep(1.0);

        break;
    case 3:
        button1 = Note.fingering[0];
        button2 = Note.fingering[1];
        button3 = Note.fingering[2];

        button1.highlighted = YES;
        button2.highlighted = YES;
        button3.highlighted = YES;

        sleep(1.0);

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

I would like to have it so that when my for loop iterates through scaleNotes, each sequence of buttons is highlighted for a moment, then the next Notes buttons are highlighted. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't name method like that.

Comment: FYI - Your method is named `tutorial:::::`. That's not a good name.

Comment: NEVER call `sleep` on the main thread, ever. Bad, bad, bad.

Comment: If you want to create an app to teach people how to play guitar (or equivalent) I suggest using UIViews to highlight fingering patterns. You can use UIView animations to make them highlight/glow and they are better suited than buttons.

Comment: I would like them to be able to press the buttons in the right finger patterns so that they can practice the scale.